# AdMob in app Adverts - Always the same one

Tags: android, admob

For the past month, I have noticed that the adverts that appear in my app (I actually use my app day-to-day) is the same one.

The ads are provided by AdMob, but I am concerned that I will stop getting revenue from other users if the adverts remain the same.

Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you login to your Admob account, in Sites & Apps panel, hover mouse on your android app, click Manage Setings -> App Settings, double check the Automatic refresh settings, make sure you are not using no refresh option.

If this does not help, check out this similar SO question discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205277/android-admob-sdk-requesting-a-new-advert-returns-same-advert)